# My EditText is weird

Tags: android

I am developing in android and something weird happens. The underline that an automatically makes doesn't position itself on the right position

In the first line of text, it's fine

[image]

this is how it acts weird when I input more than one line of text :

[image]

I tried to find all the api that might be related , but I can't find a way to make this underline properly positioned. All I did was create an edittext and called `setSingleLine(false)` . Can anyone please explain to me why this is happening ? Is this a bug ?

Comment: You want to make your text underline ?

Comment: what is your xml code?

Comment: Is the `android:height` property fixed (as in Xdp)?

Comment: @Leon_SFS Oh I do not use xml I just create edittext by java code

Comment: @y.feizi yeah. I wish the underline stays in the right position

Comment: so do u add any layout param to editbox? like "wrapcontent" or anything else for editbox size?

Comment: @Leon_SFS no I don't use any param

Comment: try it : yourEditTextName.getLayoutParams().height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT .

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: @NamHoLee you do it totally wrong ! that line is edit Text background not a text underline

Comment: @Leon_SFS Yeah it kinda does work but the line just disappeared. I think I should maybe repost this question later since my code is kinda dirty right now , thank everyone for answering

Comment: ok, so for getting best result change param to : yourEditTextName.getLayoutParams().height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT